# creating a join alias - how to?

Tags: sql, mysql, select, join, alias

I'm wanting to do something like

```
SELECT
    t.subtitle
FROM
    temp t
    LEFT JOIN ep e ON e.subtitle=t.subtitle AND e.episode=t.episode AS se
WHERE se IS NULL
GROUP BY t.subtitle, t.episode;
```

So that the where clause can refer to the result of the left join, is this possible or do I have to use a different method? (episode and subtitle are indexed in both tables)

Thanks,
Paul

**UPDATE**  When I say result I mean the left table returns no matches for e.subtitle=t.subtitle and e.episode=t.episode

Do I have to instead do

```
SELECT
    t.subtitle
FROM
    temp t
    LEFT JOIN ep e ON e.subtitle=t.subtitle AND e.episode=t.episode
WHERE e.subtitle IS NULL AND e.episode IS NULL
GROUP BY t.subtitle, t.episode;
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It doesn't make any sense - a JOIN doesn't have a result!

Comment: What is the result of a join?

Comment: Yes you do have to as per your updated example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to do that second query for the result  :)